# Best way to rename multiple columns after using nest() and map() in R

Tags: loops, dictionary, dplyr, rename, nest

I wanted to know what is the best way to rename multiple columns after using nest() and map().

I have a sample code of what I have done at the moment to achieve this using the iris dataset.

```
iris_names <- colnames(iris[, 1:4])

iris_sqrt <- iris %>% 
  nest(-Species) %>% 
  mutate(square_root = map(data, sqrt)) %>% 
  unnest(square_root)

names(iris_sqrt)[3:ncol(iris_sqrt)] <- paste0(iris_names, ".sd")
```

Here, I make a vector of the column names I want to rename before creating iris_sqrt and then renaming using paste0. The drawback of this method is the column name has to appear in the same order as the iris_names vector to rename correctly.

Is there a tidyverse/dplyr way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mutate` inside the `map` call. Use `across` on `everything`, apply `sqrt`, using the `.names` argument you can change the names of the new columns, and use `.keep = "unused"` in `mutate` to remove the columns that were used during the calculation:

```r
iris %>% 
  nest(data = -Species) %>% 
  mutate(square_root = map(data, ~ .x %>% 
                             mutate(across(everything(), sqrt, 
                                           .names = "{.col}.sd"),
                                           .keep = "unused"))) %>% 
  unnest(square_root)
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 150 × 6
   Species data              Sepal.Length.sd Sepal.Width.sd Petal.Length.sd Petal.Width.sd
   <fct>   <list>                      <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 setosa  <tibble [50 × 4]>            2.26           1.87            1.18          0.447
 2 setosa  <tibble [50 × 4]>            2.21           1.73            1.18          0.447
 3 setosa  <tibble [50 × 4]>            2.17           1.79            1.14          0.447
 4 setosa  <tibble [50 × 4]>            2.14           1.76            1.22          0.447
 5 setosa  <tibble [50 × 4]>            2.24           1.90            1.18          0.447
 6 setosa  <tibble [50 × 4]>            2.32           1.97            1.30          0.632
 7 setosa  <tibble [50 × 4]>            2.14           1.84            1.18          0.548
 8 setosa  <tibble [50 × 4]>            2.24           1.84            1.22          0.447
 9 setosa  <tibble [50 × 4]>            2.10           1.70            1.18          0.447
10 setosa  <tibble [50 × 4]>            2.21           1.76            1.22          0.316
# … with 140 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked well and seems very straight forward!